# How to create a UISplitViewController without UIPopoverController?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I need to create a UISplitViewController without a UIpopoverController? How to display both the RootViewController and DetailViewController to be displayed in Portrait mode?

Answer (score 1):

actually, there's a split view controller delegate method called

```
-(BOOL)splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation;
```

you can just return no for all the orientations so that the root view controller won't go away

Comment: But this method is not there in the UISplitViewControllerDelegate. Is there any other delegate for UISplitViewController?